# p4 merge accept theirs but actually do a merge

Tags: perforce

During `p4 resolve`, after changing my local file significantly, I have ascertained that I want to resolve all conflicts with "their" version. However, if I run `at` (accept theirs) on the prompt (which defaults to `e` edit) perforce will just overwrite the new revision of the file, and I then lose all of those changes I made.

I'd like to merge in the new changes and *only resolve conflicts by choosing theirs*. I believe this is how git behaves if "accept theirs" is given to resolve a conflict. Is there a command to tell Perforce to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perforce's `accept theirs` is different as you noted.  It chooses the source file deltas for every change, not just conflicts.

You probably want to `accept merged` and then choose how to resolve conflicts in P4Merge.